# Disable button until WPF form loads

Tags: wpf, events

I have a WPF form with Next and Prev buttons for navigating to the next and previous months of a custom made calendar. I want to disable these buttons as soon as the user clicks on them and enable them when the mext/prev month data loads. That would prevent the user from clicking on the buttons repeatedly and the events queuing up and getting fired slowly one by one.

So far, I have tried putting the calendar data load stuff in a Dispatcher thread, and maintaining a flag to indicate whether the page is busy or not. Doesn't seem to work, and the events still pile up.

I also tried using a command for the button clicks, have the execute handler load the data, and CanExecute decide whether data can be loaded, based on a IsBusy flag. Doesn't work either.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you using any design pattern, e.g. MVVM or MVC?

Comment: @AkselK: The command handlers work fine. But CanExecute always returns true, even though I am checking a class level boolean (IsBusy) value. I am setting the boolean to true in the Executed event, and setting it to false once the data loads.

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Unfortunately, I cannot share code as it is on my client network. Although if you need any specific info, I can share that.

Comment: @PVitt: We are using MVP, and this code is supposed to go in the view's code behind.

Comment: With the command, are you calling CanExecute before calling Execute?

Comment: @Sayak Can you post a generic version of your code? Specifically, what happens when you click the LoadButton, where IsBusy is set at, and how you are launching your background process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a BackgroundWorker to load the view and checking BackgroundWorker.IsBusy in the next/prev event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an event fired when the month is loaded. 
To me the best solution would be to manually disable the buttons on their click event, and enable them back when the month is loaded. 
I see no problem on adding some code behind in the view if needed.

Comment: I tried that, although it seems that the UI is updated only when the entire call is finished, i.e. when the data is loaded and displayed.

Comment: You want to enable the buttons once the next/prev month data is loaded, isn't it? Which call are you talking about? Really, some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

What type of Command are you using?

A `RelayCommand` will re-run the `CanExecute` method when one of the properties changes, however a `DelegateCommand` will not.

You need to manually raise the CanExecuteChanged event on a DelegateCommand when your CanExecute parameters change.

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsBusy")
    {
        // Might need a Cast here if your command is of type ICommand
        LoadDataCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```